# Find the value of summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If
$$xy = 3 , yz = 6 , xz = 2$$
Find the value of $x+y+z$
My attempt:

Let $$k=x+y+z$$

$$k^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +2(xy+xz + yz)$$

$$k^2 = x^2 +y^2 + z^2 +22$$

But i stopped here i need a hint

Answer (score 1):

Note
\begin{align}
(x+y+z)^2&= x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)\\
&=\frac{(xy)(zx)}{yz}+\frac{(yz)(xy)}{zx}+\frac{(zx)(yz)}{xy}+ 2(xy+yz+zx)\\
&=36
\end{align}
Thus, $x+y+z=\pm6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^2y^2z^2 = 36 \implies xyz = \pm6$

You already have value of $xy, yz, zx$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Observe that $$xyz\ne 0$$

$$\frac{yz}{xy}=\frac{6}{3}=2=xz$$

$$\implies x^2=1$$

Other approach :
The product gives
$$xyyzzx=(xyz)^2=36$$

$$\frac{x+y+z}{xyz}=\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{xz}+\frac{1}{xy}$$

The result you should find is $   \; \color{red}{\pm}6$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $x,y,z\neq 0$. Thus, $x=\frac 3y$, $z\frac3y=2$, i.e. $3z=2y$. Now your second equation gives $\frac23y^2=6$ which gives $y=\pm 3$. Thus, $x=\pm 1$ and $z=\pm 2$.

The value of $x+y+z$ thus is either $6$ or $-6$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all notice that if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution to the system then so does $(-a,-b,-c).$ Therefore we need to have at least two solutions for $k.$ Multiplying given equations gives $$x^2y^2z^2=2.3.6=36$$ and therefore $xyz=\pm 6.$ Hence $x=\pm 1, y=\pm3, z=\pm2$ and finally $$x+y+z=\pm6.$$